# "Failed to complete SSL handshake: NSS error -5938." while connecting with the retrace server

Tags: fedora, debugging

Having installed Fedora 21 and found that it works very nicely (unless you want dropbox, hardware acceleration in some things, decent video drivers & codecs etc), I have recently turned to reporting any bugs found by the bug reporter. My problem is, when I first try to report a bug using ABRT, it shows this in the output box:

```
--- Running report_uReport ---
('report_uReport' completed successfully)

--- Running analyze_CCpp ---
Ok to upload core dump? (It may contain sensitive data). If your answer is 'No', a stack trace will be generated locally. (It may download a huge amount of data). 'YES'
Querying server settings
An error occurred while connecting to 'retrace.fedoraproject.org'
Failed to complete SSL handshake: NSS error -5938.
```

It then prompts:

```
Do you want to generate a stack trace locally? (It may download a huge amount of data but reporting can't continue without stack trace).
```

Which I then confirm yes too, so it downloads the relevant debuginfo packages and continues happily to generate the trace and report any bugs. But is this SSL handshake issue with the server, ABRT, misconfiguration, or something else, and how can I determine this?

Comment: It can be that your local version of NSS only supports/is configured to accept TSL>1.1 while the server only supports TSL 1.0 https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=retrace.fedoraproject.org

Comment: @Braiam - is there any way to check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server has recently disabled SSLv3 and the client required TLSv2:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=994599

The server supports all TLS versions now.