# Mailx SSL/TLS handshake failed: Unknown error -5938

Tags: postfix, ssl, mailx

I have 2 Linux CentOS 7 machines, a Samba server and a Postfix server. The Postfix server is configured to use SASL authentication and TLS encryption. On the Samba server, I can connect to the Postfix server using openssl.

```
[root@samba1 ~]# openssl s_client 
-connect mail.example.com:587 
-starttls smtp 
-CAfile /etc/pki/tls/mail.example.com.pem
```

When I use mailx on the Samba server, I get message "**SSL/TLS handshake failed: Unknown error -5938**".

```
[root@samba1 ~]@ echo "Hello World" | mailx -v -s "Test" -A default first.last@hotmail.com
Resolving host mail.example.com . . . done.
Connecting to 192.168.0.10:587 . . . connected.
SSL/TLS handshake failed: Unknown error -5938.
```

In /var/log/maillog on the Postfix server, I do see a few TLS events.

```
Nov 25 19:23:05 mail postfix/smtpd[5659]: initializing the server-side TLS engine
Nov 25 19:23:05 mail postfix/smtpd[5659]: connect from samba1.example.com[192.168.0.12]
Nov 25 19:28:05 mail postfix/smtpd[5659]: timeout after UNKNOWN from samba1.example.com[192.168.0.12]
```

This is my /etc/mail.rc file on the Samba server.

```
[root@samba1 ~]# cat /etc/mail.rc
account default {
set smtp=smtps://mail.example.com:587

#Authentication
set smtp-auth=login
set smtp-auth-user=my.email@example.com
set smtp-auth-password="my_password"

#Encryption
set smtp-use-starttls
set nss-config-dir=/etc/pki/nssdb
}

set hold
set append
set ask
set crt
set dot
set keep
set emptybox
set indentprefix="> "
set quote
set sendcharsets=iso-8859-1,utf-8
set showname
set showto
set newmail=nopoll
set autocollapse
set markanswered
ignore received in-reply-to message-id references
ignore mime-version content-transfer-encoding
fwdretain subject date from to
set bsdcompat
```

[This article](https://forums.zoho.com/topic/what-is-unknown-error-5938) suggests to comment out smtp-use-starttls, which seems to not apply to my situation, since my Postfix server is configured to use TLS. If I comment out smtp-use-starttls, I stil get the 5938 message.

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179492/failed-to-complete-ssl-handshake-nss-error-5938-while-connecting-with-the-r) suggests that you can ensure both servers are using the same version of TLS. I added ssl-method=tls1 to /etc/mail.rc on the Samba server, and I still get the 5938 message.

Using **certutil**, I do see my certificate in /etc/pki/nssdb on the Samba server, and it is valid.

```
[root@samba1 ~]# certutil -V -n "mail.example.com.crt" -d /etc/pki/nssdb -u A
certutil: certificate is valid
```

Here is the contents of nssdb

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 65536 Nov 25 17:56 cert8.db
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  9216 Jun 26 08:51 cert9.db
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 16384 Nov 25 17:56 key3.db
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 11264 Jun 26 08:51 key4.db
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   451 Apr 25  2016 pkcs11.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 16384 Apr 25  2016 secmod.db
```

I am not certain what I should do next for this anomaly.

Comment: There are lots of possibilities here but you should start by running `mailx` in verbose mode (`-v` parm).  It appears to me that smtps should normally use port 465 and no `starttls`, so that may be your only/main problem.  Of course, the certificate validity (whether self-signed or not) could cause problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips Julie! I updated my question, adding the -v (verbose) option to the mailx command. I also updated the certutil command to show that the certificate being used is valid. I also commented out starttls, and the same problem occurs. Thank you very much for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Can you try replicating the issue from a different email client such as Thunderbird (or many others) to see what type of error they would give?  A simple certificate warning would be a likely answer.

Comment: Thanks Julie. This is where things get very interesting. On the Samba server, I am able to connect to the Postfix server using OpenSSL. Also, using a Windows machine in the network, I can connect to the Postfix server using OpenSSL. On other Windows and Linux machines in the network, I am able to connect to the Postfix server using Thunderbird. In short, it is only when using Mailx that I am not able to connect to the Postfix server.

Comment: Then you must look for the difference in settings.  Did you try port 465?

Comment: Thanks Julie. I tried on port 465, but this failed. I've Postfix configured to use port 587, and other applications, such as OpenSSL and Thunderbird are able to connect on 587. I'll double check my /etc/mail.rc configuration, comparing the configuration to OpenSSL and Thunderbird. Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: Is it a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes, the certificate is self-signed. I created the certificate and private key using OpenSSL.

Comment: It will probably work if you add the `-S ssl-verify=ignore` arg to your `mailx` command.  It could probably be put in your `mail.rc` but I can't test it.

Comment: Thanks Julie. I tried ssl-verify=ignore, and still error 5938 appears.

Comment: Please show me your full command line.

Comment: Thanks Julie. I updated my question with my complete /etc/mail.rc file and contents of my /etc/pki/nssdb directory.

Comment: `smtps:` means to _initially connect_ with SSL/TLS, which 587 does not support. You want to connect _then_ start SSL/TLS, which is generically called starttls. Use `smtp=server:587` (no smtps:) and `smtp-use-starttls` (not commented).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I made the changes you recommended, and the problem is solved. The SSL/TLS handshake is successful, and I am able to connect to Postfix using mailx. If you would like to post your comment as the answer, I would love to accept your answer.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 would you like to write up your comment as an Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dave_thompson_085](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/59699/dave-thompson-085) [answered in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326118/mailx-ssl-tls-handshake-failed-unknown-error-5938#comment573814_326118):

> smtps: means to initially connect with SSL/TLS, which 587 does not support. You want to connect then start SSL/TLS, which is generically called starttls.

Use:

```
smtp=server:587
```

and

```
smtp-use-starttls
```